# Is it possible to (easily) create new types in python

Tags: python, types

I would like to know if there is an easy way to create 'custom' types in Python.

I created a function that takes a parameter which is currently a MAC address. I would like to change it so it would be either an IP address or a MAC address then check the 'type' inside the function for further processing.

In order to do so I can check with regexes but I wonder if I could define two types, ip_add and mac_add, and check my parameter's type before processing it.

I read something about defining new types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html) but it's not straightforward at all. Maybe there's a particular package existing ?

Comment: Why not simply construct two classes `IPAdd` and `MACAdd` and let these classes validate the content?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) module - why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Not sure why you're talking about types here, classes are what you want.

Comment: I think the OP referenced to the wrong chapter. That chapter is to construct new types at *interpreter* level.

Comment: Just use class for your own type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The doc you link to in your question](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/newtypes.html) is for creating new types in C in the CPython runtime (the "interpreter") for C-coded extensions. Python has a much more straightforward way to create new types in Python module: [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Defining a new class is as simple as:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, dob):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.dob = dob
    def say_hello(self):
       return "Hello, my name is {self.firstname} {self.lastname} and I was born on {self.dob}".format(self=self)

p = Person("bruno", "desthuilliers", "May 1st, 1967")
p.say_hello()
```

This being said, as AK47 rightly mentions, [the netaddr package](http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) seems to already provide the features you're looking for.